# org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value;

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-redis

Below class is storing the token to token store and it is working fine till the upgrade to the version 2.7.16.
There is no issues with jdk 8 and spring boot 1.5.3, but after upgrading to spring boot 2.7.16 and java to 21, I am getting exception. How to fix this error

```
public class ThirdPartyTokenService extends DefaultTokenServices {
    private TokenStore tokenStore;
    @Override
    public OAuth2AccessToken createAccessToken(OAuth2Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
     try {
        OAuth2RefreshToken refreshToken = null;
        OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = this.createThirdPartyAccessToken(authentication);
            tokenStore.storeAccessToken(accessToken, authentication);
            // In case it was modified
            refreshToken = accessToken.getRefreshToken();
            if (refreshToken != null) {
                tokenStore.storeRefreshToken(refreshToken, authentication);
            }
            return accessToken;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
     }
    }

}
```

The code is working properly in spring boot 1.5.3-RELEASE but in spring boot 2.7.16 I am getting the below exception

In spring boot 2.7.16 it is throwing exception while calling tokenStore.storeAccessToken(accessToken, authentication);

The above call goes to org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.redis.RediSTokenStore,In the below method and after closing the pipeline it throws the exception. Exception is caused by the existing spring framework code.
added one pom entry for redis as below

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
        <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Existing spring boot starter redis kept as it is

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Below is the method from spring framework RedisTokenStore

```
public void storeAccessToken(OAuth2AccessToken token, OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
        byte[] serializedAccessToken = serialize(token);
        byte[] serializedAuth = serialize(authentication);
        byte[] accessKey = serializeKey(ACCESS + token.getValue());
        byte[] authKey = serializeKey(AUTH + token.getValue());
        byte[] authToAccessKey = serializeKey(AUTH_TO_ACCESS + authenticationKeyGenerator.extractKey(authentication));
        byte[] approvalKey = serializeKey(UNAME_TO_ACCESS + getApprovalKey(authentication));
        byte[] clientId = serializeKey(CLIENT_ID_TO_ACCESS + authentication.getOAuth2Request().getClientId());

        RedisConnection conn = getConnection();
        try {
            conn.openPipeline();
            if (springDataRedis_2_0) {
                try {
                    this.redisConnectionSet_2_0.invoke(conn, accessKey, serializedAccessToken);
                    this.redisConnectionSet_2_0.invoke(conn, authKey, serializedAuth);
                    this.redisConnectionSet_2_0.invoke(conn, authToAccessKey, serializedAccessToken);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(ex);
                }
            } else {
                conn.set(accessKey, serializedAccessToken);
                conn.set(authKey, serializedAuth);
                conn.set(authToAccessKey, serializedAccessToken);
            }
            if (!authentication.isClientOnly()) {
                conn.sAdd(approvalKey, serializedAccessToken);
            }
            conn.sAdd(clientId, serializedAccessToken);
            if (token.getExpiration() != null) {
                int seconds = token.getExpiresIn();
                conn.expire(accessKey, seconds);
                conn.expire(authKey, seconds);
                conn.expire(authToAccessKey, seconds);
                conn.expire(clientId, seconds);
                conn.expire(approvalKey, seconds);
            }
            OAuth2RefreshToken refreshToken = token.getRefreshToken();
            if (refreshToken != null && refreshToken.getValue() != null) {
                byte[] refresh = serialize(refreshToken.getValue());
                byte[] access = serialize(token.getValue());
                byte[] refreshToAccessKey = serializeKey(REFRESH_TO_ACCESS + refreshToken.getValue());
                byte[] accessToRefreshKey = serializeKey(ACCESS_TO_REFRESH + token.getValue());
                if (springDataRedis_2_0) {
                    try {
                        this.redisConnectionSet_2_0.invoke(conn, refreshToAccessKey, access);
                        this.redisConnectionSet_2_0.invoke(conn, accessToRefreshKey, refresh);
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
                    }
                } else {
                    conn.set(refreshToAccessKey, access);
                    conn.set(accessToRefreshKey, refresh);
                }
                if (refreshToken instanceof ExpiringOAuth2RefreshToken) {
                    ExpiringOAuth2RefreshToken expiringRefreshToken = (ExpiringOAuth2RefreshToken) refreshToken;
                    Date expiration = expiringRefreshToken.getExpiration();
                    if (expiration != null) {
                        int seconds = Long.valueOf((expiration.getTime() - System.currentTimeMillis()) / 1000L)
                                .intValue();
                        conn.expire(refreshToAccessKey, seconds);
                        conn.expire(accessToRefreshKey, seconds);
                    }
                }
            }
            conn.closePipeline();
        } finally {
            conn.close();
        }
    }
```

Below is the exception

```
org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisPipelineException: Pipeline contained one or more invalid commands; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.convertPipelineResults(JedisConnection.java:470)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.closePipeline(JedisConnection.java:435)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.redis.RedisTokenStore.storeAccessToken(RedisTokenStore.java:236)
    at com.gtl.industryapp.auth.middleware.config.ThirdPartyTokenService.createAccessToken(ThirdPartyTokenService.java:120)
    at com.gtl.industryapp.auth.middleware.config.ThirdPartyTokenService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$bfac2d6a.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:792)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:762)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:762)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:707)
    at com.gtl.industryapp.auth.middleware.config.ThirdPartyTokenService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fdbfd8e2.createAccessToken(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.AbstractTokenGranter.getAccessToken(AbstractTokenGranter.java:76)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.AbstractTokenGranter.grant(AbstractTokenGranter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.CompositeTokenGranter.grant(CompositeTokenGranter.java:42)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer$4.grant(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer.java:587)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint.postAccessToken(TokenEndpoint.java:137)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1072)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:965)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:555)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:337)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:196)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:112)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:221)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:926)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1790)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisExceptionConverter.convert(JedisExceptionConverter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisExceptionConverter.convert(JedisExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.PassThroughExceptionTranslationStrategy.translate(PassThroughExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:44)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.translate(FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:42)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.convertJedisAccessException(JedisConnection.java:192)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.convertPipelineResults(JedisConnection.java:457)
    ... 120 more
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.processError(Protocol.java:142)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:176)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:230)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.readProtocolWithCheckingBroken(Connection.java:355)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getMany(Connection.java:367)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Pipeline.sync(Pipeline.java:98)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I solved this issue(exception) by changing the jar to a compatible version as below. Now it is working fine. This issue is due to the dependency compatibility issue.

In the pom.xml, I changed the dependency version

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```